# format specifier of percent sign with Poco Formatter

Tags: c++, poco, format-specifiers

while using Poco::format
I am trying to print the following line:
"3% and 5%"

```
int var1 = 3
int var2 = 5
std::string s;
s = format("%?d%% and %?d%%",var1,var2);
```

instead of getting "3% and 5%",
s equals "3 ?d%"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: C++ and C are different languages, choose one. No reason to use both.

Comment: `std::string s = format("%d%% and %d%%",var1,var2);` should do the job. Why the question marks between `%` and `d`?

Comment: @mch
Hi, thanks for the answer. The question mark is to specify that it can be either 32bit or 64bit
I actually tried without it as you suggested before, and it is still printing d instead of the value of the second argument